How to update WooCommerce order meta from one field to another?
I have a site that automatically updates orders from an ERP system. The ERP system adds a few fields into the order meta table that we'd like to post to an array. The plugin we are using to track shipments is the WooCommerce Shipment Tracking. They give a handy PHP snippet to create the array which I've used. I am trying to find a way to have this function run anytime the order is updated and if the tracking array is empty. When I tested this snippet we got a critical error of PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() on bool . I've used this function on various other projects to get the order's meta and have not gotten this error. Here is my full code:
function post_tracking_ns_to_array( $order ) {
        global $order;
        // Run through the order
        // Get the NS Fields
        $tracking_number = $order->get_meta('_tracking_number'); //get the _tracking_number field
        $provider = $order->get_meta('_tracking_provider'); //get the _tracking_provider field
        // Other Fields
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $date_shipped = date("Y-m-d"); //get the current date
        $custom_url = '';
        
        //Update the Shipment Tracking Box with the new fields
    if( $order_id && $tracking_number && $provider && $date_shipped ) {
            if ( function_exists( 'wc_st_add_tracking_number' ) ) { 
                wc_st_add_tracking_number( $order_id, $tracking_number, $provider, $date_shipped, $custom_url ); 
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'post_tracking_ns_to_array' );

Is there anymore I am missing or am I possibly not grabbing the "current" order correctly? This function would need to run whenever it detects the "_tracking_number" field being added on a completed order.
Attempted a few variations of the get meta and how to get the order including:
function post_tracking_ns_to_array() {
    global $order;
    $order = get_id(); 
}

#2:
function post_tracking_ns_to_array() {
    global $wp;
    $order = wc_get_order();
}

All of these result in the same issue. For reference, we are using HPOS.
